# Have I installed and started zram successfully?

Tags: zram

On my Kubuntu 13.10 laptop, have installed zram by

```
sudo aptitude install zram-config
```

and the output of

```
swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda5                               partition       6150140 0       -1
/dev/zram0                              partition       373300  0       5
/dev/zram1                              partition       373300  0       5
/dev/zram2                              partition       373300  0       5
/dev/zram3                              partition       373300  0       5
/dev/zram4                              partition       373300  0       5
/dev/zram5                              partition       373300  0       5
/dev/zram6                              partition       373300  0       5
/dev/zram7                              partition       373300  0       5
```

As you can see, /dev/sda5 comes before /dev/zram*, is this setup correct? How can I make sure that zram is working properly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes your setup is correct. The fact that zramX devices are present is good indicator that it's working properly. If not, you should see an error message in syslog.

If you are paranoid, you can make sure that zram is working properly by benchmarking it.

There is a simple benchmark, with expected results, on the [zram wiki](http://code.google.com/p/compcache/wiki/zramperf).